# why different frames height in chrome and IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

i have two frames in one html page, which display correctly in chrome browser.but when i tried  in IE7 it just looks very strange,its height is not 100% any more !the below is the code .

```
<iframe src ="demoFramesetLeftFrame.jsp" name="treeframe" id="treeframe" height="100%" width="200px" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
<iframe src="" name="basefrm" id="basefrm" height="100%" width="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

i can't see any error in the code.does anyone knows what is the problem? thanks a million !

Comment: Do you have an appropriate DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this rule defined in your CSS

```
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0 }
```

Comment: it seems do not work, i try again but it still displays different height in different browser.

Comment: this is the css code below:

#treeframe{
 width:200px; 
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 frameborder:0
}
#middle{
 width:30px; 
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 frameborder:0
}
#basefrm{
 width:0px; 
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 frameborder:0
}